# C# not waiting for all Tasks to be performed

Tags: c#, multithreading, request, locking, task

I'm trying to execute multiple requests at the same time to a Pi Number API. The main problem is that despite the 'Task.WhenAll(ExecuteRequests()).Wait();' line, it isn't completing all tasks. It should execute 50 requests and add it results to pi Dictionary, but after code execution the dictionary has about 44~46 items.
I tried to add an 'availables threads at ThreadPool verification', so i could guarantee i have enough Threads, but nothing changed.

The other problem is that sometimes when I run the code, i have an error saying I'm trying to add an already added key to the dicitionary, but the lock statement wasn't supposed to guarantee this error doesn't occur?

```
        const int TotalRequests = 50;
        static int requestsCount = 0;
        static Dictionary<int, string> pi = new();
        static readonly object lockState = new();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();

            Task.WhenAll(ExecuteRequests()).Wait();

            timer.Stop();

            foreach (var item in pi.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
                Console.Write(item.Value);

            Console.WriteLine($"\n\n{timer.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            Console.WriteLine($"\n{pi.Count} items");
        }

        static List<Task> ExecuteRequests()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < TotalRequests; i++)
            {
                ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out int workerThreads, out int completionPortThreads);

                while (workerThreads < 1)
                {
                    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    var currentRequestId = 0;

                    lock (lockState)
                        currentRequestId = requestsCount++;

                    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    var result = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start={currentRequestId * 1000}&numberOfDigits=1000");

                    if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(json)!["content"]!.ToString();
                        //var content = (await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<JsonObject>(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)!)!)!)!["content"]!.ToString();

                        pi.Add(currentRequestId, content);
                    }
                }));
            }

            return tasks;
        }
```

Comment: " but the lock statement wasn't supposed to guarantee this error doesn't occur?" - I don't see any locking around dictionary manipulation - are you sure you've posted correct code as part of [mre]? (Also it is confusing why you must use actual HTTP requests for your sample when `Task.Delay()` is probably enough - double check if you really can't simply the example)

Comment: Are you sure all your http requests are succeeding?

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeiLevenkov! I just put an extra lock around the dicitionary manipulation and it worked fine!
Yes @JohnWu the requests are all suceeding

Comment: ​As a side note, the `HttpClient` class is intended to be instantiated [once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), and reused throughout the life of an application. Also the `while (workerThreads < 1)` loop seems redundant, and your code doesn't make use of the convenient new API [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) (.NET 6).

Comment: `result` also needs a `using`, and if you keep instantiating `HttpClient` you will probably get socket exhaustion

Answer (score 0):

I put a lock statement around the dicitionary manipulation as @AlexeiLevenkov mentioned and it worked fine.

```
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    var currentRequestId = 0;

                    lock (lockState)
                        currentRequestId = requestsCount++;

                    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    var result = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start={currentRequestId * 1000}&numberOfDigits=1000");

                    if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(json)!["content"]!.ToString();
                        //var content = (await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<JsonObject>(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)!)!)!)!["content"]!.ToString();

                        lock (lockState)
                            pi.Add(currentRequestId, content);
                    }
                }));
```

Answer (score 0):

There`s only one problem - you turned only **one** part of code, which have problem with threads:

```
lock (lockState)
     currentRequestId = requestsCount++;
```

But, there`s another one:

```
pi.Add(currentRequestId, content);
```

The problem related to dictionary idea - a lot of readers and only **one** writer. So, you saw case with exception and if you write try catch, you will see [AggregateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-6.0), which almost in every case mean thread issues, so, you need to do this:

```
lock (lockState)
     pi.Add(currentRequestId, content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not directly answering the question, just suggesting that you can use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    (int currentRequestId, string content)[] results = ExecuteRequests(50).ToArray().Wait()

    timer.Stop();

    foreach (var item in results.OrderBy(x => x.currentRequestId))
        Console.Write(item.content);

    Console.WriteLine($"\n\n{timer.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    Console.WriteLine($"\n{results.Count()} items");
}

static IObservable<(int currentRequestId, string content)> ExecuteRequests(int totalRequests) =>
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
        from currentRequestId in Observable.Range(0, totalRequests)
        from content in Observable.Using(() => new HttpClient(), hc =>
            from result in Observable.FromAsync(() => hc.GetAsync($"https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start={currentRequestId * 1000}&numberOfDigits=1000"))
            where result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
            from json in Observable.FromAsync(() => result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
            select JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(json)!["content"]!.ToString())
        select new
        {
            currentRequestId,
            content,
        });
```